# screen with mpirun

Tags: screen, mpi

MPI works fine:

```
$ mpirun -np 2 -H compute-0-0,compute-0-1 echo 1
1
1
```

However it does not work when launched via screen:

```
$ rm -f screenlog.*
$ screen -L mpirun -np 2 -H compute-0-0,compute-0-1 echo 1
[screen is terminating]
$ cat screenlog.0 
mpirun: error while loading shared libraries: libimf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This does not help:

```
$ rm -f screenlog.*
$ screen -L `which mpirun` -xLD_LIBRARY_PATH -np 2 -H compute-0-0,compute-0-1 echo 1
[screen is terminating]
$ cat screenlog.0 
/share/apps/intel/openmpi/bin/mpirun: error while loading shared libraries: libimf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Is that a Rocks cluster?)

Apparently you're not getting the right `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for some reason.

This isn't a very clean solution, but it should work:

```
$ screen -L env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH mpirun -np 2 \
  -H compute-0-0,compute-0-1 echo 1
```

<strike>I assume that's what you were trying to do with the `-xLD_LIBRARY_PATH` option, but I don't see that in the [documentation](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www1/mpirun.html) I was able to find.</strike>

That's what you were trying to do with the `-xLD_LIBRARY_PATH` option, but that's only going to pick up the value of `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` from within the process invoked by `screen` (and pass it on to the `echo 1` command).  By that time it's too late.  Also, the [man page](http://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.4/man1/mpirun.1.php) suggests that there should be a space: `-x LD_LIBRARY_PATH`; I don't know whether it's required.

Is there some script you're sourcing to get the environment (including `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`) for MPI?  Is it sourced automatically in your login shell startup, or do you do it manually?  You might want to write a small wrapper script that sources the setup script and then invokes a specified command.  Something like (not tested):

```
#!/bin/sh
. /share/apps/intel/openmpi/etc/setup.sh # probably not the right name
exec "$@"
```

Save it as `$HOME/bin/mpienv.sh`, then you can use:

```
$ screen -L mpienv.sh mpirun -np 2 -H compute-0-0,compute-0-1 echo 1
```

Comment: Yep, it's a rock cluster. Indeed, the right value for $LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set in .bashrc.
I confirm that both solutions you propose work on my side (not absolutely perfect, but OK). Thanks!

Comment: Does the `env` trick work?  Try replacing `echo 1` with `printenv`.

Comment: Indeed LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not set for screen.
screen -L printenv
does not display any LD_LIBRARY_PATH. So that's a problem solely with screen.

Comment: Interesting.  I get the same result, but other variables set in my startup scripts are set properly; just `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `$NLSPATH` are missing.  (And there are no references to either name in the `screen` sources, so it doesn't seem to be something `screen` is doing deliberately.)